# Binary Search Explanation

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

Link: https://leetcode.com/problems/first-bad-version/discuss/71386/An-clear-way-to-use-binary-search

I am doing a question wherein, given a string like this "FFTTTT", I have to find either the rightmost `F` or the leftmost `T`.

The following is the code:

`To find the leftmost T`

```
public int firstBadVersionLeft(int n) {
    int i = 1;
    int j = n;

    while (i < j) {

        int mid = i + (j - i) / 2;

        if (isBadVersion(mid)) {
            j = mid;
        } else {
            i = mid + 1;
        }

    }

    return i;

}
```

I have the following doubts:

1. I am unable to understand the intuition behind returning `i`. I mean, why didn't we return `j`. I did a trial run of the code in my mind, and it works out, but how do we know we have to return `i`.
2. Why didn't we do `while (i<=j)` and just `while(i<j)`. I mean, how do we determine this?

Comment: On your first question: do return j instead, and see what the difference is.

Comment: On your second question: what would happen if it was all Ts or Fs with `while(i<=j)`?

Answer (score 0):

1. You stop when i==j as far as I can tell. So you can return either of them since they have the same value.
2. The difference between the two conditions is `i == j` . In that case `mid == i + 0/2 == i`. So isBadVersion can return true or false. If it returns true then you do j= mid, but we already had `i == j == mid`, so you don't do anything and you have an infinite loop. If isBadVersion returns false then you will make `i == j+1` and the loop will end. Since the boundaries are inclusive (they include the i'th and j'th element) this can only happen if there's no 'T' in the string. 
   So you do `(i < j)` to avoid that infinite loop case.

P.S. This code will return n if there's not 'T' in the string or the last character is a 'T'. Not sure if that's intended or not.